# What taxes does Afghanistan impose on US citizens?

Tags: taxes, us-citizens, afghanistan

I'd like to know what taxes Afghanistan now imposes on US citizens working there. The last time I was there were none but a friend of mine who has a family member there told me Afghanistan now does charge taxes -- but I'd like to verify that along with the effective tax rate.

Comment: Is the US citizen working for a private employer or in a diplomatic or quasi diplomatic capacity?

Comment: I'd be interested in knowing about both.

Comment: Well the latter are generally exempt from taxation under international law, so that answer would be fairly easy and unsatisfying, but I mainly mentioned it to offer a possible reason for the apparent inconsistency you observed: it might not be a difference in Afghan law but in the circumstances of the workers.

Comment: Possible ... but not in this case.

Comment: I honestly don't think they impose taxes, I mean the whole country is a mess, what makes you think that they will charge you on taxes?

Comment: Did you see the answer from a week earlier that gives that actual tax rates ... along with the link?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer [here](https://contractortaxation.com/Afghanistan/Tax-In-Afghanistan/). It's a variable tax rate based on salary in Afgahani, not dollars.

```
| Gross Income    |      tax rate    |
|-----------------|------------------|
|  0-60,000       | 0%               |
|  60,000-150,000 | 2%               |
|150,000-1,200,000| 10% + AFN1800    |
|  1,200,000      | 20% + AFN106,800 |
```

Can you file it online? : No